# How to convert sql query to django orm query?

Tags: sql, django

We are using django and sql, so we have written query in sql , here my request is how can I convert sql query to django query.Please let me know

Comment: where is the sql query? where is your django model?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ModelName.objects.raw()` to run SQL queries which will return model Instances.

Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/

or to execute directly from Database import `connections` from `django.db`.

Refer:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Note: Django ORM is secure than normal SQL. If using raw SQL queries read docs on how to make raw SQL queries secure.